# Is it secure to repeatedly rehash a digest to extend the digest length?

Tags: hash, random-number-generator, post-quantum-cryptography, sha-512

Upon reading through the source code of [Rainbow](https://www.pqcrainbow.org/), a post-quantum signature algorithm, I found a [hashing function](https://github.com/fast-crypto-lab/rainbow-submission-round2/blob/173ada0e077e1b9dbd8e4a78994f87acc0c92263/Optimized_Implementation/amd64/Vc_Circumzenithal/utils_hash.c#L76) that, using SHA-512, produced a variable length digest.

This was achieved was by initially hashing the message to obtain a 64 byte digest, and then hashing that digest, and again, each time hashing the `N - 1` digest. It's essentially being used as a deterministic CSPRNG.

Is this secure? Can SHA-512's digest be stretched out indefinitely like this? And why didn't Rainbow simply use a well-studied CSPRNG like ChaCha20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 2.6 of their submission talks about this.
There they state that for most cases they simply use SHA-256, -384 or -512.
In the (uncommon?) case that a hash function with a larger output is needed, they use the OFB-like<sup>1</sup> construction.
The rationale being that a collision on the OFB construction would immediately imply a collision on the underlying hash function - as the direct output is part of the expanded output.
This also explains why they don't want to involve another (more efficient) function: To reduce security guarantees and prefer simplicity over optimization for rarely needed scenarios.

---

<sub>1: [OFB-Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#OFB) is a way to construct a PRG and an CPA-secure encryption scheme out of a fixed-length PRF. It works essentially as $K_i=F_k(K_{i-1})$ outputting $K_1\|K_2\|\ldots\|K_\ell$ for a PRF $F$ and a secret random key $k$.</sub>

Comment: OFB mode and PRGs, in which $f$ is a *private* random function, are a lot different than hashing, where $f$ is a *public* random function. If $f$ is a public random oracle, and $K_i = f(K_{i-1})$ then I can easily distinguish $K_1\|K_2\|\cdots\|K_n$ from random.

Comment: @Mikero excellent point, I have adapted my answer to no longer potentially confuse people into using OFB as an RO extender.